# Laravel 7: Validation error message is not showing using key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-7

I want to show validation errors right next to the field.
Therefore I am using this the @error directive.

```
@error('service_date')
    <div class="error">{{ $message }}</div>
@enderror
```

But the error only shows up when iterating over all of them.

```
@if($errors->any())
    {{ implode('', $errors->all('<div>:key - :message</div>')) }}
@endif
```

Using the above method, I can see that the key is correct. The output will be as follows:

*service_date - The service date is not a valid date.*

Other errors in the same form get displayed correctly.  Why is behaving like this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Use instead `@if($errors->has('service_date'))
   <div class="error">{{ $errors->first('service_date') }}</div>
@endif`

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't resolve my error - still not showing anything.